# How do I get chrome to UNPIN all pinned tabs before closing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs, tabs

It really bums me out that Chrome maintains your pinned tabs on startup.

I use an extension that manages/saves/organises previous sessions/windows, and when I start chrome, I have "Open a specific page or set of pages" set to that extensions main page.

This works great, except when I have pinned tabs open in the last window to close in my previous session.

I use different windows/sessions depending on what I'm doing. If I'm doing digital art work, I'll want a different set of chrome windows than if I'm just browsing the web, or doing some development, etc. Each of these windows/sessions has different pinned tabs, which Chrome insists on remembering. So, I need something that will unpin ALL tabs whenever I close a window.

There is no option I can see to tell Chrome to simply FORGET about any previous tabs, so I'm wondering if there's an extension anyone knows of to simply unpin and close all tabs, when the last Chrome window is closed? Or to make Chrome IGNORE any pinned tabs from last time when it opens its first window?

Comment: Easy enough. Don't pin tabs in multiple windows. Use something like OneTab and bundle them instead.

Comment: I just created my own plugin eventually. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of a pinned tab is to open at startup of google chrome. If you don't want them to open at startup, you'll have to unpin them.

Inside the options of google chrome, there is already a built-in option to open specific tabs at startup. So there is no need for that extension that you have installed.

You can choose this by:

1. Click the 3 dots in the right top of the screen
2. Choose **options**
3. Scroll down till: **at startup**
4. Choose the third option: **open a specific page or set of pages**
5. Then you can simply add those pages by adding the url at **add a new page**

Comment: Yup, I have that done already. The problem is that I have 5-10 pinned tabs in 5+ windows at any given time. Manually unpinning them ALL, EVERYTIME I close/open Chrome is a huge time waste and PITA. My session manager extension will restore the pinned tabs I actually want, if I want them.

Comment: So, what is the problem than?

Comment: I use different windows/sessions depending on what I'm doing. If I'm doing digital art work, I'll want a different set of chrome windows than if I'm just browsing the web, or doing some development, etc. Each of these windows/sessions has different pinned tabs, which Chrome insists on remembering. So, I need something that will unpin ALL tabs whenever I close a window.

Comment: You should edit this last comment into your original question to clarify why you want those pinned tabs to be closed.